# sql select all from table where username in array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am trying to print some cd names in to an array from a SQL database which previously I had selected but everywhere I get the same results. Can you help me? I was trying to add [$x] in different locations in code on the second php but get the same error.

I only get the first selected cd name from database where username= loggein_user.

```
require 'connectmysql.php';
//COUNT how many cart history has each user   
mysql_select_db('shop');
$data = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(Username) AS num FROM cart WHERE Username = '{$_SESSION['Username']}' ") or die(mysql_error());
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
$numUsers = $row2['num'];

$_SESSION['count_cart_history'] = $numUsers;

mysql_close($con);
```

The Problem is somewhere under the for loop but I can't find it. I was trying to change it like $result = .... or $row3 = .... without [$x] but nothing.

```
for($x=0;$x<=$_SESSION['count_cart_history']; $x++)
{
    $selecthistory[$x] = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE Username = '{$_SESSION['Username']}'";

    $result[$x] = mysql_query($selecthistory[$x], $con);
    $row3[$x] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result[$x]);

    // $_SESSION['historymarket_id'][$x]   = $row3[$x]["Market_ID"];
    $_SESSION['historycd_name'][$x]     = $row3[$x]["CD_NAME"]; 
    // $_SESSION['historydate_sold'][$x]   = $row3[$x]["Date_Sold"]; 
    // $_SESSION['historyprice'][$x]     = $row3[$x];["Price"]; 
    // $_SESSION['historytotalprice'][$x]  = $row3[$x]["TotalPrice"]; 
    // $_SESSION['historyquantity'][$x]    = $row3[$x]["Quantity"]; 
    // $_SESSION['historycredit'][$x]      = $row3[$x]["Credit"]; 
}       

echo'edw';
echo $_SESSION['historycd_name'][0];
echo $_SESSION['historycd_name'][1];
echo $_SESSION['historycd_name'][2];

for($x=0;$x<=$_SESSION['count_cart_history']; $x++)
{

?>
  <p>
    Market_ID :
    <input name="market_id" type="text"  readonly value=" <?php //echo $_SESSION['historymarket_id'][$x]; ?>">
  </p>
  <p>
    CD Name :
    <input name="CD_NAME" type="text" readonly value="<?php echo $_SESSION['historycd_name'][$x];  ?>">
  </p>
  <p> 
    Date Sold :
       <input name="Date_Sold" type="text" readonly value="<?php //echo $_SESSION['historydate_sold'][$x]; ?>">
  </p>
  <p> 
     Price:  
       <input name="price" type="text" readonly value="<?php //echo $_SESSION['historyprice'][$x]; ?>">
  </p>
  <p> 
     Total Price:  
       <input name="totalprice" type="text" readonly value="<?php //echo $_SESSION['historytotalprice'][$x]; ?>">
  </p>
  <p>Credit Card:
    <input name="Credit" type="text" readonly value="<?php //echo $_SESSION['historycredit'][$x];   ?>">
  </p>
   <p>Quantity:
    <input name="quantity" type="text" readonly value="<?php //echo $_SESSION['historyquantity'][$x];  ?>">
  </p>
  <p>PostAddress:
    <input name="PostAddress" type="text" readonly value="">
  </p>

<?php }  mysql_close($con);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the same `SELECT` query on every loop, so all the items you store will be the same.

You could try something like this:

```
$x = 0;
$selecthistory = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE Username = '{$_SESSION['Username']}'";
$result = mysql_query($selecthistory[$x], $con);
// loop through all the items from the cart
// this will loop $_SESSION['count_cart_history'] times as long as the count hasn't changed
while($result && $row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // $_SESSION['historymarket_id'][$x]   = $row3["Market_ID"];
    $_SESSION['historycd_name'][$x]        = $row3["CD_NAME"]; 
    // $_SESSION['historydate_sold'][$x]   = $row3["Date_Sold"]; 
    // $_SESSION['historyprice'][$x]       = $row3["Price"]; 
    // $_SESSION['historytotalprice'][$x]  = $row3["TotalPrice"]; 
    // $_SESSION['historyquantity'][$x]    = $row3["Quantity"]; 
    // $_SESSION['historycredit'][$x]      = $row3["Credit"];
    $x++;
}
```

It is recommended that you do not use `mysql_` functions; instead upgrade to `mysqli_` functions. You should also escape your `$_SESSION['Username']` before using it in the query.